# how to download a file from url and save in location using unity3d in C sharp?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

iam working on unity3d project. i need set of files to be downloaded from the server. iam using C# for scripting. after a hour of google i haven't found a solution because of poor documentation. can anyone give me example code for download file from url and save it in a specific location in unity3d?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unity3D uses the implementation of C# known as Mono. Mono supports [almost everything](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility) available in the standard .NET library. Thus, whenever you are wondering 'How do I do that in Unity?', you can always take a look at the documentation for .NET available at [msdn.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx37x362.aspx) which is by no way poor. Regarding your question, use the `WebClient` class:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        Stream data = client.OpenRead(@"http://google.com");
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        data.Close();
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

**Edit**
When downloading an image file, use the `DownloadFile` method provided by `WebClient`:

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 client.DownloadFile("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Google.png", @"C:\Images\GoogleLogo.png")
```

Comment: Thank you., How to download a image file?

Comment: Typically, asynchronous downloading is preferred over synchronous downloading as shown here. Unity's now has a builtin `UnityWebRequest` that supports asynchronous downloading in coroutines.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the WWW functions in Unity 3d.

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public string url = "http://images.earthcam.com/ec_metros/ourcams/fridays.jpg";
    IEnumerator Start() {
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;
        renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
    }
}
```

Asset bundles if you are looking to compress your data packets.

```
var www = new WWW ("http://myserver/myBundle.unity3d");
    yield www;
    // Get the designated main asset and instantiate it.
    Instantiate(www.assetBundle.mainAsset);
```

Note that some functions are only Ready only... like the www.url function. Some of the examples have been moved to the Manual section instead of the scripting section as well.

Hope this helps.

-Mark

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.Net.WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) to download file asynchronously.

something like

```
   System.Net.WebClient client = new WebClient();
   client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("your uri"), "save path.");
```

I found a good example ,that can use with unity3d [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707709/downloading-large-file-in-unity3d-using-webclient/29710414#29710414)

Answer (score 0):

Unity's `WWW` class & method group has been deprecated. Using `UnityWebRequest` is the current recommended method for handling web requests, especially [GET requests](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-RetrievingTextBinaryData.html):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class MyBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(GetText());
    }

    IEnumerator GetText() {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://www.my-server.com");
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else {
            // Show results as text
            Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);

            // Or retrieve results as binary data
            byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
        }
    }
}
```