# Downloading large file in Unity3d using WebClient

Tags: c#, asynchronous, unity-game-engine, download, webclient

I am looking for any ideas regarding downloading large (100mg+) files in Unity3d using WebClient.  WWW runs asynchronously and would be perfect except it returns a memory error and crashes the app, so I have moved to the solution as outlined here:

[how to download a file from url and save in location using unity3d in C sharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428062/how-to-download-a-file-from-url-and-save-in-location-using-unity3d-in-c-sharp)

This works like a dream *except* it shuts down all the scripts in my app until the download is complete.  I cannot seem to even run a loading bar at the same time as the download is going on.  I have tried handling this by adding a coroutine to handle the download, but so far, no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.  My code currently (after many iterations) looks like:

C#

```
 void Update()
    {
    //Sets up the timer so I can use it to watch the debugging
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log (timer);

//Checks to see if the file was already downloaded and saved.  If not, it begins downloading.
    if (FileExists == 0 && timer >= 5) {
        StartCoroutine ("DOWNLOAD");

    } 
//If the file already exists, it jumps straight to the next scene.
    else if (FileExists == 1) {
        Application.LoadLevelAsync ("Different_Level");
    }

    //These are the buttons.  One should stop the download if the player decides they don't want to wait.
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {

        RaycastHit rc_hit;
        Ray hud_ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

    if (Physics.Raycast (hud_ray, out rc_hit, Mathf.Infinity, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer ("HUD"))) {

    if (rc_hit.transform.gameObject == b_BackButton) {

        StopCoroutine ("EN_Loop");
        Application.LoadLevelAsync ("Other_Level"); 
                            }
                    }
            }

}

//This is what should happen when the video is done downloading
void AllDone ()

{
    Debug.Log ("Download Complete");
    Application.LoadLevelAsync ("Next_Level");
}

////This is the coroutine I created int he hopes that I could get the download to run in the background.
IEnumerator DOWNLOAD()
{
    Debug.Log("downloading_EN");
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadFile ("http://ServerInfo.net/moviefile.mp4", Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "moviefile.mp4");
    yield return null;

    AllDone ();

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit, Alex Art.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using WebClient.DownloadFileAsync to not lock up the main thread (so your other scripts will still run)  and use the WebClient.DownloadFileCompleted event to know when it's completed.

There's no need to use a Coroutine for using the WebClient and make sure to only call this Method once:

```
void DownloadFile()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler( DownloadFileCompleted );
    client.DownloadFileAsync ((new Uri ("http://ServerInfo.net/moviefile.mp4", Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "moviefile.mp4"));
}

void DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        AllDone ();
    }
}
```

More information on DownloadFileAsync:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

And DownloadFileCompleted Event:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hi James!  This is stellar, but AsyncCompletedEventHandler is throwing a "could not be found" error.  I have "using System.Net" declared at the top of the script, am I missing a component?

Comment: I am using Unity 4.5 with MonoDevelop - Unity 4.0.1

Comment: Hey Kimberly, you want to add the following decleration at the top of your script:

"using System.ComponentModel;", I've updated the example to use this explicitly where needed.

Comment: Brilliant :) This does the trick!  Only two things to add to your edits, it seems we have to keep the "new" in front of the AsyncCompleted and the Uri of the download location also needs to be declared as new (I've made edits to your answer, hope you don't mind).

Comment: I know this is over a year old, but the bugs in WWW in Unity are still a problem...  and using this fixed all my memory leak woes with it.  Thank You Kimberly!

Comment: @KimberlyUnger Kimberly, how can I track download progress with DownloadFileAsync?

Comment: Hi @GuardFromUA!  I don't have a code example for you, I didn't track the download on this project.  But you should be able to check how many bytes have been downloaded and compare that number to the expected download size to track your progress.

Comment: Hello, @KimberlyUnger I've ended up with the same solution) Thank you a lot.

Comment: Thank god !. It's work like a charm. 
and it can use with android device too.