# Unity3D, yield return www blocking main thread in iOS

Tags: ios, web, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I faced a weird situation during creation of iOS 64 support build through Unity3D,
the yield return www call is blocking the main thread on device.

I tried Unity version 4.6.5, 4.6.6, and 5.1.0 and faced the same problem with WWW class.
I tried xCode version 6.3.0, 6.3.1, 6.3.2 also.

Below is the code snippet I am using

```
private IEnumerator StartDownload(string url, string path)
{
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www; //blocking main thread
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        Debug.Log("File Download Complete");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Error in downloading file, Error: " + www.error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *only* way I can conceive of it blocking the main thread is if you are not calling it as a Coroutine correctly...

Correct call:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(StartDownload("http://google.com", ""));
}
```

The call then run deferred (in main thread) but will not block the thread. It will be polled until it is done.

Incorrect way (that will block main thread):

```
void Start()
{
    IEnumerator a = StartDownload ("http://google.com", "");
    while (a.MoveNext()) {}
}
```

Comment: Hi @peterept
I am using StartCoroutine(StartDownload("http://google.com", ""));
The problem is with iOS only, In Android, Unity Editor the same code is running perfectly.
Any help for iOS.

Comment: Please check the sample code [link](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/yield-return-www-blocking-main-thread-in-ios.337637/)

Comment: I build on iOS all the time, and use all the Unity versions you mention. (Although on Xcode not the 6.3 versions you mention). But I would suggest if coroutines broke on iOS there would be a lot of apps effected. Can you clarify what you mean by "block the main thread" then? Blocking means nothing runs, you can easily check that by pressing pause in the debugger. But maybe you are just "frozen" by settings Time.timescale = 0 somewhere?

Comment: Hi @peterept. I dont know, what wrong i am doing, but the same code was working till Unity version 4.6.2, after updating to version 4.6.5, we faced this issue. For small files upto 2 MB no problem, but if i start file about 20 mb. the frame rate stuck till the cache not completed. Please take a look of code [link](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/yield-return-www-blocking-main-thread-in-ios.337637). My major concern for Asset Bundle Caching, when I call yield return WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(path, 1) frame rate freezes for few seconds

Comment: Thanks for the link. The thing is you have a 50MB asset bundle with 3235 assets in it and it takes time for Unity to save that file and process the index when parsing the bundle. For saving such a large file you can write it out yourself in chunks, or split the bundle into multiple bundles.

Answer (score 0):

I've never saw a `yield return www;` blocking for the entire download, but I did encounter this:

- if you are downloading a large asset (more than a couple of megs)
- and have a fast internet connection (more than 2 MB/s)
- you'll see the UI thread freezing

This is happening because even though the download happens on a different thread when Unity is copying the data from the download buffer to the final location the copying is done the UI Thread and if the disk operation goes over 2 MB/s then the thread is blocked.

The bug is in the Unity `WWW` implementation for iOS. 
If this is your case I can provide you with the changes I made to fix this.

Comment: The code i Wrote is working fine for Android and Unity Editor, It is creating problem in iOS only.
My major concern for Asset Bundle Caching, when I call 
yield return WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(path, 1) frame rate freezes for few seconds, The Asset Bundle size is 18 and 22 MB each.

find the Sample code
[link](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/yield-return-www-blocking-main-thread-in-ios.337637)

Comment: yes, it only happens on iOS because the implementation is different on iOS. I've decompiled the WWW sources for android and the implementation takes care of this and this is why you don't have the problem

Comment: @RaduDita What are your fixes? Care to post them? That'd be really helpful!

Comment: I can dig the fixes I made, but they don't work with the latest Unity release. The code responsible for copying the data was moved from objective-c in a closed source dll and I didn't found a way around it.

Comment: @RaduDita I see. But for the record, one can work around it by using WebClient.DownloadFileAsync() (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707709/downloading-large-file-in-unity3d-using-webclient/29710414#29710414)  and AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync() (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync.html)